# Customizing the Main Menu in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devtools

This sounds very simple, but I am frustrated for the past few hours to get this done.
I am not able to see "Macros" sub menu under "Tools" menu in Visual Studio 2008.

I go to Tools->Customize->Commands. 
Select Tools under Categories and click Rearrange Commands. Instead of showing me the Tools Menu it shows me Files.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug in VS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

In the Rearrange Commands dialog box, click the drop-down box at the top where it says "File" and then scroll down to the Tools menu. You should be able to add it there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Once we choose Commands, we have to choose the appropriate tool and then drag and drop the item on to the menu bar.